# Best Practices for using AASM in a Rails API Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, aasm

We are using [acts_as_state_machine (AASM)](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) in our Rails app to control flow of models from one state to the next in a traditional finite state-machine. We are building out an API for our application, and as part of that we'd like to be able to trigger state transitions when a Rails model is updated based on the state that is passed into the `update` Controller method by the API user.

A simplified version of the state-machine looks like this:

```
aasm :column => :state do
    state :proposed, :initial => true
    state :published
    state :retired

    event :publish do
      transitions :from => :proposed, :to => :published
    end

    event :retire do
      transitions :from => :published, :to => :retired
    end
end
```

One option is to use remote-procedure call (RPC) style, where we provide `/model/{ID}/publish` and `/model/{ID}/retire` style endpoints. This is fairly straight forward, but isn't very RESTful.

Another option we've considered is inspecting the parameters and transitioning based on the incoming `state` property of the model. This feels like a "better" approach in that our API is kept simpler for the consumer, but it adds a lot of complexity to the controller in terms of logic.

What's the best way to implement the triggering of AASM state events for a Rails API? Are we missing an option?

Answer (score 1):

personally, I tend to have two kinds of calls - straight class-REST calls and state transitions, the most common one being an enabled? I would use what's most intiuitive and not worry about it being un-RESTful esp because I find the state transitions can have a different set of logic. In other words RPC - style